# How to load bot chat context in tdlib java?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot, tdlib

I am developing service for interaction with Telegram using tdlib in java. Log in with botToken as a bot.

If I try to send a message to the chat on behalf of the bot immediately after the Client has successfully authorized, I get an error

> Chat not found

In order to send a message, you need to send a message to the bot again on behalf of the user (although there was already a chat before). As a result, each time the application is restarted, it will be necessary to wait for an incoming message from the user, which is wrong.

When trying to send a request

```
client.send(new TdApi.GetChats(new TdApi.ChatListMain(), 1000), resultHandler);
```

I get an answer

```
Error {
  code = 400
  message = "The method is not available to bots"
}
```

I don't understant why methods are not available for bots. Which are available? I also tried LoadChats, the result is the same.

**The question is how can I immediately load the chat context when the application starts without waiting for an incoming message from the user?**

Tdlib documentation for java is very poor. Any links about bots abilities in tdlib will be very helpfull.